# Ajuda com algoritmo de interpolação bicubica

Tags: c++, imagem, algoritmo

Estou tentando implementar o algoritmo de interpolação bicubica mas estou tendo muita dificuldade com o acerto dos valores interpolados( não é relacionado a pegar os valores da matriz original e sim o relacionamento dos pesos das distâncias).

Seguindo a ideia desse rapaz aqui (esse caso é para a interpolação bilinear mas ajuda a entender a ideia dos pesos) :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341167/bilinear-interpolation

Nesse caso, os pesos para uma imagem de ampliação de fator 2 ficaria : `0 0.5 1`( aqui mudaria para próximo pixel da imagem original).

Mas em uma interpolação bicubica são usados 16 pixels como mostrado na imagem a seguir :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que cria  tipo uma " mascara 4x4 " dos pixels originais, ou seja só mudaria o index quando x ou y passar de 3. Fiz uma lógica para esse index e funciona mas a minha duvida está relacionado ao dx e ao dy pois eles terão que ir de 0 a 3 ( pois é a distância horizontal e vertical ) ponderados entre 0 e 1 certo ? ou seja, para uma ampliação de fator 2 eles terão que ir de `0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3`( ponderado seria `0 0.1666 0.25 0.5 0.666 0.83 1` )  ?

Estou fazendo com esses pesos e jogando no polinômio, que pode ser visto aqui : http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic

Mas os valores estão muito a quem do desejado ( embora esteja pegando os pixels certinho e fazendo o algoritmo certo).

A ideia da manipulação dos pesos ponderados é assim mesmo ? Ou está incorreto ?

Se puder explicar de forma mais exemplificada esse algoritmo para ver se estou pensando da forma correta eu agradeceria.

EDITADO :

Por exemplo, considere a matriz a seguir :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se formos aumentá-la em ordem 2 ficaria com seus respectivos pesos ficaria algo do tipo  :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se fizermos

```
P= Cubo(pixel[index],pixel[index+1],pixel[index+2],pixel[index+3],dx);
Q= Cubo(pixel[index+4],pixel[index+5],pixel[index+6],pixel[index+7],dx);
R= Cubo(pixel[index+8],pixel[index+9],pixel[index+10],pixel[index+11],dx);
S= Cubo(pixel[index+12],pixel[index+13],pixel[index+14],pixel[index+15],dx);

matriz[i][j] =Cubo(P,Q,R,S,dy);
```

onde o cubo seria essa função :

```
Cubo(double[] p, double x) { 
 return p[1] + 0.5 * x*(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2.0*p[0] - 5.0*p[1] + 4.0*p[2] - p[3] + x*(3.0*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0]))); 
}
```

Se fizermos isso para o valor da  linha 0 e coluna 1 ( dx = 0.1666 e dy=0) vai gerar  `{ 5.04 ,1.98, 1.69, 3.02}`  e o resultado disso  `matriz[i][j] =Cubo(5.04 ,1.98, 1.69, 3.02, dy)` vai ser `1.98` enquanto que deveria dar algo entre `8 e 5`.

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo de errado ?

Comment: Marque na pergunta a tag em que linguagem isso está sendo feito.